# how to change TTStyledTextTableItemCell 's background

Tags: ios, uitableview, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

Suppose I create `TTTableStyledTextItem` objects in `<TTTableViewDataSource>` conforming class as follows:

```
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<b>%@</b>\n%@", @"aaaa..", @"bbbb.."];
TTStyledText* styledText = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:text lineBreaks:YES URLs:NO];
TTTableStyledTextItem* item = [TTTableStyledTextItem itemWithText:styledText URL:@"my://url"];
```

By default, the table view cell class returned by `tableView:cellClassForObject:` is going to be `TTStyledTextTableItemCell`.

This works all right by I'd like to customize the background color of the cell when it is in the normal state (when it is not in the selected state).

I've managed to change the cell's background in the selected state by creating a `TTStyledTextTableItemCell` subclass and overriding the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` initializer as follows:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    if (self) {
        // WORKS!
        // cell's backgroundview (selected)
        UIView *selectedView          = [[UIView alloc] init];
        selectedView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor someColor..];
        self.selectedBackgroundView   = selectedView;

        // DOESN'T WORK
        // cell's background (normal)
        UIView *normalView          = [[UIView alloc] init];
        normalView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor someColor..];
        self.backgroundView         = normalView;
    }

    return self;
}
```

but I can't find a way to change the background of the cell when it's not selected (`self.backgroundView`). I know that there's an associated `TTStyledTextLabel` subview in the `TTStyledTextTableItemCell` class, but I still have no success customizing it.

Is there an easy way to achieve this??
Thanks